# concatenation array name with numeric variable

Tags: jquery, arrays

I've got a couple of arrays, named `array_1`, `array_2` till `array_5`.

Depending on a certain level, I want to use an array, let's say when `level = 1` use `array_1`.
When I try: `myArr = array_ + level`  I can't approach `myArr` as an array (I declared `myArr` as an array).

How do I concatenate '`array_`' with 'number `1`'.

Comment: where are stored these arrays ? could try `window["array_"+level]` if arrays are globals

Comment: pls refer this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var arrayName = "array_" + "1";
var requiredArrayName = window[arrayName];
```

Comment: The arrays are stored as globals. window["array_" + "1"] doesn't work. I tried  window["array_" + level.toString()] and that doesn't work either.